# Finding an Abelian subgroup

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I am working on my homework and am currently stuck at the following question:

> Let $\mathcal S_{10}$ be the group of all permutations of the set of elements {1, 2, ..., 10}. Find an Abelian subgroup of size 24 to $\mathcal S_{10}$.

Thanks a lot in advance for any advice/hints! :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Take the cycles

$$\sigma:=(1234)\;,\;\;\tau:=(56)\;,\;\;\pi:=(7,8,9)$$

and now check the group $\;\langle \sigma,\tau,\pi\rangle\le S_{10}\;$ . First thing to get convinced of: this subgroup is abelian.

Further hint: up to isomorphism there are three different abelian groups of order $\;24\;$  :

$$C_{24}\;,\;\;C_4\times C_2\times C_3\cong C_{12}\times C_2\cong C_6\times C_4\;,\;\;C_2\times C_2\times C_2\times C_3\cong C_2\times C_2\times C_6$$

The first one is impossible in $\;S_{10}\;$ (why? Check the possible disjoint cycles decomposition), so we're left only with possibilities $\;2,3\;$ . The example I gave above fits with case $\;2\;$. Can you come up with an example of case $\;3\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$\langle (1,2,3,4,5,6)\rangle \times \langle(7,8,9,10)\rangle$ which sits inside $\mathcal S_{10}$ as a direct product since the two groups do not intersect, and element-wise commute with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: <(123456)(78910)>

Comment: all cyclic subgroups are abelian.

Comment: And the order is 24 because the order of a product of distinct cycles is the lcm of the lengths of those cycles. So $|<(123456)(78910)>|=6*4=24$.

Comment: The order of that group is $\;12\;$ , not $\;24\;$: $\;lcm(4,6)=12\;$ ...

Comment: As DonAntonio mentioned, the order of this group is $12$. Perhaps you could try conjugacy classes?

Comment: you can not expect a cyclic sub group of $S_{10}$ of order $24$ as order of any element in $S_{10}$ can be one of  $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,15,18,20,21,30\}$.. it would be better if you can first make sure these are the only possible orders..

Comment: Scuse me, I was meaning ronno solution. I won't correct to be more didactic.